# iTunes parameter 'ign-mpt=uo%3D4'

Tags: itunes, url-parameters

Anyone know what the 'ign-mpt=uo%3D4' parameter in iTunes URL signifies?

Example. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/empire-four-kingdoms/id585661281?mt=8&ls=1&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this as well.. Just came across this parameter.. No documentation online... Anyone???

Comment: I guess is about referral code. Something like a referenced invite.

Answer (score 1):

This is added to the link by the [Apple Affiliate Program](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/). They have a script to automatically convert iTunes links in affiliate iTunes links. Once I've activated this script, the new parameter was added (at runtime) to all my iTunes/Appstore links.